# Publishing Karate test report to Cucumber Open Report

Tags: cucumber, karate

Hi Do you know if there is a way of publishing Karate cucumber reports by using Cucumber Open? I have recently seen that cucumber enables publishing reports to a cloud-based environment which makes sharing the reports with others very easy. [cucumber-open-link](https://cucumber.io/blog/open-source/cucumber-reports/)

I have tried a number of ways such as adding @CucumberOptions as annotation to the ParallelRunner class, but failed to make Cucumber find the feature files to run (or when it found the features files, this time failed to find the step definitions).

I will be happy to hear from anyone in the Karate community who may have experimented using this version of cucumber reporting with Karate, or any other ideas.
Thanks all for your time.

Comment: the linked question has all the available info, and you should consider investigating and contributing code. since karate is "bigger" than cucumber now, you should probably ask them to support karate ;) https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/1424259563503587330 - and karate is NOT cucumber at all, so things like `@CucumberOptions` simply won't work, sorry

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas, in fact the base of what I was trying to do was to publish the reports to an online service and so that I could share the link, but like you suggested, I will search Allure reporting as well.